# Is there a way to choose a different location for the Earth detail lock screen?

Tags: ios, screen-lock

In iOS 16 I want to use the Earth detail Lock Screen but with a location *other* than my current location. Seems that this is not supported but has anyone found a hack or trick to choose a different center for the map?

Comment: I still wonder about the purpose of the green dot. Usually I know where I am anyway, and it kind of looks ugly. But an option to select a different location would be nice.